# Lead and Account custom duplication check

Tags: apex, soql, loop

In the following method:

```
public List<Id> getLeadIds(Lead[] listOfLeads) {
    List<Id> leadIds = new List<Id>();
    for (Lead lead : listOfLeads) {
        if (lead.Company != null && lead.Rating != null) {
            List <Account> listOfAccounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Account.Name = :lead.Company AND Account.Rating = :lead.Rating AND Account.Status__c != 'Cancelled'];
            if (listOfAccounts.size() > 0) {
                leadIds.add(lead.id);
            }
        }
    }
    return leadIds;
}
```

Method `getLeadIds` is invoked every time when new Lead records are created.
Each Lead is compared to all NOT cancelled Account records and checked for duplicates by Account name and Account rating.
The issue I have is that the SOQL query is inside the for loop which is giving me: `Too many SOQL queries` error message.
How to implement the `getLeadIds` method where the SOQL query is outside the for loop?

Comment: This requirement appears at first blush to be implementable without code using Salesforce's native **Duplicate Management** feature. Have you considered doing so?

Comment: [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm) do exactly this without using code. You can directly call the dupe rules & get duplicate data returned. Your root problem is calling soql inside of a loop. For each record you make at least one query, you'll hit your limit quickly this way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you want to gather your info to build your account query ahead of time and then run your filters on the accounts in the database vs. leads in memory. So, something like this:

```
public Set<Id> getLeadIds(Lead[] leads) {

    Map<Id, Lead> id2Lead = new Map<Id, Lead>(leads);
    Set<String> companies = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> ratings = new Set<String>();

    Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Lead lRec : id2Lead.values()){
        companies.add(lRec.Company);
        ratings.add(lRec.Rating);
    }

    List<Account> accts = [
        SELECT      Name, Rating
        FROM        Account    
        WHERE       Name IN :companies AND
                    Status__c != 'Cancelled' AND
                    Rating IN :ratings
        ORDER BY    Name ASC, Rating ASC
    ];


    for(Lead lRec : id2Lead.values()){
        for(Account acct : accts){
            if (
                lRec.Company != null &&
                lRec.Rating != null &&
                lRec.company.equalsIgnoreCase(acct.Name) &&
                lrec.Rating  == acct.Rating
            ){
                leadIds.add(lRec.Id);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return leadIds;

}
```

Having said that, this method checks against accounts in your database.

Said another way, s'pose you have n Leads in this transaction with the same company name, rating info, etc/ then both those n leads would be returned by this method. is that ok, or are you handling that use case elsewhere?

EDIT: Alternative implementation.

```
 public Set<Id> getLeadIds(Lead[] leads) {

    Map<Id, Lead> id2Lead = new Map<Id, Lead>(leads);
    Set<String> companies = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> ratings = new Set<String>();

    Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Lead lRec : id2Lead.values()){
        companies.add(lRec.Company);
        ratings.add(lRec.Rating);
    }

    Set<LeadAcctMatch> acctInfoSet = new Set<LeadAcctMatch>(); 

    for(Account acct : [
        SELECT      Name, Rating
        FROM        Account    
        WHERE       Name IN :companies AND
                    Status__c != 'Cancelled' AND
                    Rating IN :ratings
        ORDER BY    Name ASC, Rating ASC
    ]){
        acctInfoSet.add(new LeadAcctMatch(acct.Name.toUpperCase() , acct.Rating.toUpperCase()));
    }


    for(Lead lRec : id2Lead.values()){
        if( lRec.Company != null && lRec.Rating != null){

            LeadAcctMatch theLead = new LeadAcctMatch(lRec.Company.toUpperCase(), lRec.Rating.toUpperCase());
            if(acctInfoSet.contains(theLead)){
                leadIds.add(lRec.Id);
            }
        }
    }
    return leadIds;
}

class LeadAcctMatch{
    String company;
    String rating;

    LeadAcctMatch(String company, String rating){
        this.company = company;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion PartOfTheOhana. It is vital however to avoid `nested` for loops. Is that possible and how to do that? Please advise.

Comment: The SOQL is not nested. ..

Comment: Yes indeed. You are correct. But it is really important for me to avoid `nested` for loops. Please advise how it can be achieved?

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. but it would add additional complexity. What's the reasoning to avoid that?

Comment: I realize that, however by avoiding `nested` loops I strive to achieve better code maintainability and efficiency by reducing Apex CPU time limits.

Comment: I added a second implementation for you...